# i can't showing up image in springboot using thymleaf

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i put images in static folder.

when i tried these codes, the image does not shows up  but only words i wrote in alt and icon that when image cannot be shown.

is there any codes that i needed to be add or fix?

this is my code in html

```
                <div th:if="${hotelTitle != null}" th:each="picDto:${hotelTitle}">
                <img th:src="@{|/payment/${picDto.URL}|}" alt="title"/>
                </div>
```

and this is code in controller

```
        Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
        int hotel_id = 1;
        String type = "title";
        paramMap.put("hotel_id", hotel_id);
        paramMap.put("type", type);
        
        List<String> hotelTitle = paymentService.searchHotelTitle(paramMap);
        
        mav.addObject("hotelTitle",hotelTitle);
```

i want to show up images that i put in static folder (for instance, 1_title.png)

but I don't know why and where to fix it